# tf.dataset, multiple path inputs, and mapping per batch to load images

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, tensorflow-datasets

I'm loading a dataset with multiple input images. The input image paths should only be decoded at batch time, in order to handle a large dataset.

The data set is **N** image path inputs and **M** float outputs.  The images for each input have different resolutions.

```
Data is ([img_input_1.png, img_input_2.png, ...], [0.65, 0.7, 0.8])
```

The model is using the Keras functional api in symbolic mode.

Here is the most recently EDITED code

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def read_image(path, shape):
    try:
        image = tf.io.read_file(path)
        image = tf.image.decode_png(image)
        image = tf.image.resize(image, [shape[1],shape[2]])
        image /= 255.0
        return image
    except:
        print('ERROR: preprocess_image: bad path', path)    

def load_image(x, y, shp):
    pout = [(k, x[k]) for k in x.keys()]
    l1   = tf.convert_to_tensor(list(x))
    l2   = tf.convert_to_tensor(list(x.values()))

    pl = tf.map_fn(
        lambda args: (read_image(args[0], shp), args[1]), [l1, l2], dtype=(tf.float32, tf.float32)
    )
    pl = {path: (pl[0][i], pl[1][i]) for i, path in enumerate(x)}
    return (pl,y)

def dataset_prep(json_data, seq, batch_size):
    # LOAD DATA FROM JSON
    x,y = json_parse_x_y(json_data[seq])
    xx  = [*zip_longest(*x)] # NOTE: goes from variable sized input to {'input_N':...}
    yy  = [*zip_longest(*y)]

    # GET SHAPES (hard coded atm)
    lns = [[len(xxx)] for xxx in xx]
    rzs = [[24,512,1],[96,512,1]] # TEMP TODO! grab grom [(v['h'],v['w'],v['c']) for v in xx]
    shp = [*zip_longest(*[lns,rzs])]
    shp = [list(s) for s in shp]
    shp = [[*itertools.chain.from_iterable(s)] for s in shp]

    xd  = dict([[ "input_{}".format(i+1),np.array(y)] for i,y in [*enumerate(xx)]])
    yd  = dict([["output_{}".format(i+1),np.array(y)] for i,y in [*enumerate(yy)]])

    ds  = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xd, yd))

    ds  = ds.shuffle(10000)
    ds  = ds.repeat()
    ds  = ds.map(map_func=lambda x,y: load_image(x, y, shp), num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    ds  = ds.batch(batch_size) if batch_size else ds 
    ds  = ds.prefetch(AUTOTUNE) 
    return ds
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/me/.local/bin/wavfeat", line 11, in <module>
        load_entry_point('wavfeat==0.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'wavfeat')()
    File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wavfeat/__main__.py", line 91, in main
        analysis_batch_sql(obj)
    File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wavfeat/analysis_run_csv.py", line 50, in analysis_batch_sql
        qy = [*map(lambda c: run_elm(c[0], c[1]), ch)]
    File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wavfeat/analysis_run_csv.py", line 50, in <lambda>
        qy = [*map(lambda c: run_elm(c[0], c[1]), ch)]
    File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wavfeat/analysis_run_csv.py", line 23, in run_elm
        out = fn(input, elm)
    File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wavfeat/one_sec_onset.py", line 196, in one_sec_onset_train
        return train(input, elm)
    File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wavfeat/one_sec_onset.py", line 182, in train
        ts = dataset_prep(jd, 'train', bc)
    File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wavfeat/one_sec_onset.py", line 123, in dataset_prep
        ds  = ds.map(map_func=lambda x,y: load_image(x, y, shp), num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1146, in map
        self, map_func, num_parallel_calls, preserve_cardinality=True)
    File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3264, in __init__
        use_legacy_function=use_legacy_function)
    File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 2591, in __init__
        self._function = wrapper_fn._get_concrete_function_internal()
    File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1366, in _get_concrete_function_internal
        *args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1360, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
        graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
    File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1648, in _maybe_define_function
        graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
    File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1541, in _create_graph_function
        capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
    File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 716, in func_graph_from_py_func
        func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 2585, in wrapper_fn
        ret = _wrapper_helper(*args)
    File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 2530, in _wrapper_helper
        ret = func(*nested_args)
    File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wavfeat/one_sec_onset.py", line 123, in <lambda>
        ds  = ds.map(map_func=lambda x,y: load_image(x, y, shp), num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wavfeat/one_sec_data_loader.py", line 91, in load_image
        print("x['input_1'].values(): ", x['input_1'].values())
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'values'
```

What am I doing that is preventing the paths from being loaded?

EDIT:

Attempting pandrey's fix, I'm getting input errors. Here is the data before from_tensor_slices and ds.map and then after:

```
pre_from_tensor_slices x:  {'input_1': array(['/media/me/sp_data/sp_data/datasets/chr_01/one_sec_onset_11_oac-leg/7388_39216_30--id=7388__sql_table=oac_1__sql_idx=405167__pitch=30__onset=39216.png',
       '/media/me/sp_data/sp_data/datasets/chr_01/one_sec_onset_11_oac-leg/2447_864_27--id=2447__sql_table=oac_1__sql_idx=415458__pitch=27__onset=864.png',
       '/media/me/sp_data/sp_data/datasets/chr_01/one_sec_onset_11_oac-leg/2386_20208_38--id=2386__sql_table=oac_1__sql_idx=433248__pitch=38__onset=20208.png',
       ...,
       '/media/me/sp_data/sp_data/datasets/chr_01/one_sec_onset_11_oac-leg/6261_24528_57--id=6261__sql_table=oac_1__sql_idx=449753__pitch=57__onset=24528.png',
       '/media/me/sp_data/sp_data/datasets/chr_01/one_sec_onset_11_oac-leg/3727_22944_31--id=3727__sql_table=oac_1__sql_idx=407620__pitch=31__onset=22944.png',
       '/media/me/sp_data/sp_data/datasets/chr_01/one_sec_onset_11_oac-leg/1668_7056_60--id=1668__sql_table=oac_1__sql_idx=381152__pitch=60__onset=7056.png'],
      dtype='<U162'), 'input_2': array(['/media/me/sp_data/sp_data/datasets/mel_01/one_sec_onset_11_oac-leg/7388_39216_30--id=7388__sql_table=oac_1__sql_idx=405167__pitch=30__onset=39216.png',
       '/media/me/sp_data/sp_data/datasets/mel_01/one_sec_onset_11_oac-leg/2447_864_27--id=2447__sql_table=oac_1__sql_idx=415458__pitch=27__onset=864.png',
       '/media/me/sp_data/sp_data/datasets/mel_01/one_sec_onset_11_oac-leg/2386_20208_38--id=2386__sql_table=oac_1__sql_idx=433248__pitch=38__onset=20208.png',
       ...,
       '/media/me/sp_data/sp_data/datasets/mel_01/one_sec_onset_11_oac-leg/6261_24528_57--id=6261__sql_table=oac_1__sql_idx=449753__pitch=57__onset=24528.png',
       '/media/me/sp_data/sp_data/datasets/mel_01/one_sec_onset_11_oac-leg/3727_22944_31--id=3727__sql_table=oac_1__sql_idx=407620__pitch=31__onset=22944.png',
       '/media/me/sp_data/sp_data/datasets/mel_01/one_sec_onset_11_oac-leg/1668_7056_60--id=1668__sql_table=oac_1__sql_idx=381152__pitch=60__onset=7056.png'],
      dtype='<U162')}
pre_from_tensor_slices y:  {'output_1': array([0.817, 0.018, 0.421, ..., 0.511, 0.478, 0.147])}
_________________________
y:  {'output_1': <tf.Tensor 'args_2:0' shape=() dtype=float64>}
x:  {'input_1': <tf.Tensor 'args_0:0' shape=() dtype=string>, 'input_2': <tf.Tensor 'args_1:0' shape=() dtype=string>}
x.values():  dict_values([<tf.Tensor 'args_0:0' shape=() dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'args_1:0' shape=() dtype=string>])
x['input_1']:  Tensor("args_0:0", shape=(), dtype=string)
```

Running x['input_1'].values() throws an error: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'values'

I get an error situated around map_fn

```
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 284, in _constant_impl
    allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 455, in make_tensor_proto
    raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
ValueError: None values not supported.
```

EDIT 2

Attempting the latest I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/.local/bin/wavfeat", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('wavfeat==0.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'wavfeat')()
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wavfeat/__main__.py", line 91, in main
    analysis_batch_sql(obj)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wavfeat/analysis_run_csv.py", line 50, in analysis_batch_sql
    qy = [*map(lambda c: run_elm(c[0], c[1]), ch)]
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wavfeat/analysis_run_csv.py", line 50, in <lambda>
    qy = [*map(lambda c: run_elm(c[0], c[1]), ch)]
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wavfeat/analysis_run_csv.py", line 23, in run_elm
    out = fn(input, elm)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wavfeat/one_sec_onset.py", line 216, in one_sec_onset_train
    return train(input, elm)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wavfeat/one_sec_onset.py", line 203, in train
    vs = validation_prep(jd, 'validation', bc)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wavfeat/one_sec_onset.py", line 176, in validation_prep
    ds  = ds.map(map_func=load_and_preprocess_from_path_label, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1146, in map
    self, map_func, num_parallel_calls, preserve_cardinality=True)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3264, in __init__
    use_legacy_function=use_legacy_function)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 2591, in __init__
    self._function = wrapper_fn._get_concrete_function_internal()
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1366, in _get_concrete_function_internal
    *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1360, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1648, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1541, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 716, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 2585, in wrapper_fn
    ret = _wrapper_helper(*args)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 2530, in _wrapper_helper
    ret = func(*nested_args)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wavfeat/one_sec_data_loader.py", line 47, in load_and_preprocess_from_path_label
    pl   = dict([(pk, tf.map_fn(load_and_preprocess_image, po, dtype=tf.float32)) for pk,po in pout])
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wavfeat/one_sec_data_loader.py", line 47, in <listcomp>
    pl   = dict([(pk, tf.map_fn(load_and_preprocess_image, po, dtype=tf.float32)) for pk,po in pout])
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/map_fn.py", line 214, in map_fn
    raise ValueError("elems must be a 1+ dimensional Tensor, not a scalar")
ValueError: elems must be a 1+ dimensional Tensor, not a scalar
```

Comment: I think you should consider reforming the question -> What it suppose to do, What do you expect, what is not working ;)

Comment: can you provide us some data sample?

Comment: I can't provide the data.  The format is simple. Two png filepaths in and a float out.  The paths test ok.  It's supposed to generalize to models with any number of png input paths and any number of float outputs (usually 1, 2, 3...).  itertools.zip_longest is splitting the in and out tuples into individual lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Add-on: not using dict structures

This is a full code (save for defining `json_parse_x_y` and declaring `AUTOTUNE`) to achieve what you are attempting without using dict structures.

I tested that `make_dataset` works (see example below), so if you encounter an issue it should be due to a specification error regarding `load_tensors`.

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

import tensorflow as tf

# additionnally, `json_parse_x_y` must be defined
# and `AUTOTUNE` must be declared (in my example, I set it to 2)


def read_image(path, shape):
    """Read an image of givent filepath and tensor shape.

    Return a float tensor of given shape.
    """
    try:
        image = tf.io.read_file(path)
        image = tf.image.decode_png(image)
        image = tf.image.resize(image, [shape[1], shape[2]])
        image /= 255.0
        return image
    except:
        raise FileNotFoundError("preprocess_image: bad path '%s'" % path)


def load_images(paths, shapes):
    """Load an ensemble of images (associated with a single sample).

    paths  : rank-1 string Tensor
    shapes : list of images' shapes (same length as `paths`)

    Return a tuple of float tensors containing the loaded images.
    """
    return tuple((
        read_image(paths[i], shapes[i])
        for i in range(len(shapes))
    ))


def load_tensors(json_data, seq):
    """Load images descriptors from a json dump.

    Return a tuple containing:
        * a rank-2 tensor containing lists of image paths (str)
        * a rank-2 tensor containing resolution values (float)
        * a list of image shapes, of same length as the rank-2
          tensor's second axis
    """
    x,y = json_parse_x_y(json_data[seq])
    xx  = [*zip_longest(*x)] # NOTE: goes from variable sized input to {'input_N':...}
    yy  = [*zip_longest(*y)]

    # GET SHAPES (hard coded atm)
    lns = [[len(xxx)] for xxx in xx]
    rzs = [[24,512,1],[96,512,1]] # TEMP TODO! grab grom [(v['h'],v['w'],v['c']) for v in xx]
    shp = [*zip_longest(*[lns,rzs])]
    shp = [list(s) for s in shp]
    shp = [[*itertools.chain.from_iterable(s)] for s in shp]
    return (xx, yy, shp)


def make_dataset(xx, yy, shp, batch_size):
    """Build a Dataset instance containing loaded images.

    xx, yy, shp : see the specification of `load_tensors`'s outputs
    batch_size  : batch size to set on the Dataset

    Return a Dataset instance where each batched sample is a tuple
    containing two elements: first, a tuple containing N loaded images'
    rank-3 tensors; second, a rank-1 tensor containing M float values.
    (to be clear: batching adds a dimension to all those tensors)
    """
    data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xx, yy))
    data = data.shuffle(10000)
    data = data.map(lambda x, y: (load_images(x, shapes), y))
    data = data.repeat()
    data = data.batch(batch_size) if batch_size else data
    data = data.prefetch(AUTOTUNE) 
    return data


def dataset_prep(json_data, seq, batch_size):
    """Full pipeline to making a Dataset from json."""
    xx, yy, shapes = load_tensors(json_data, seq)
    return make_dataset(xx, yy, shapes)
```

Example, using "hand-made' values ; all images are actually
[this classic image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Lenna_%28test_image%29.png), of shape [512, 512, 3].

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# import previous code

# Here, N = 2, and I make 2 samples.
x = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([
    ['image_1a.png', 'image_1b.png'],
    ['image_2a.png', 'image_2b.png']
]))
shapes = [[1, 512, 512], [1, 512, 512]]  # images are initially [512, 512, 3]
# Here, M = 3, and I make 2 samples. Values are purely random.
y = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([
    [.087, .92, .276],
    [.242, .37, .205]
]))

# This should work.
data = make_dataset(x, y, shapes, batch_size=1)
# Output signature is <PrefetchDataset shapes:
#     (((None, 512, 512, None), (None, 512, 512, None)), (None, 3)),
#     types: ((tf.float32, tf.float32), tf.float64)
# >
# Where the first None is actually `batch_size`
# and the second is, in this case, 3.
```

---

#### Answer to the current question:

Okay, the problem you are now encountering is that the revised `load_image` function does not fit the specifications of the Dataset, hence the exception raising. Please find below a full edited code that seems to work (I ran a test using custom images on my computer, with `xd` / `yd` dict initialized to look like your reported x and y in-dataset tensors). It is not pretty, and I would personally advise to drop the dict structures, but it works:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

def read_image(path, shape):
    try:
        image = tf.io.read_file(path)
        image = tf.image.decode_png(image)
        image = tf.image.resize(image, [shape[1],shape[2]])
        image /= 255.0
        return image
    except:
        raise FileNotFoundError("preprocess_image: bad path '%s'" % path)

# CHANGED: load_image is actually useless

def dataset_prep(json_data, seq, batch_size):
    # LOAD DATA FROM JSON
    x,y = json_parse_x_y(json_data[seq])
    xx  = [*zip_longest(*x)] # NOTE: goes from variable sized input to {'input_N':...}
    yy  = [*zip_longest(*y)]

    # GET SHAPES (hard coded atm)
    lns = [[len(xxx)] for xxx in xx]
    rzs = [[24,512,1],[96,512,1]] # TEMP TODO! grab grom [(v['h'],v['w'],v['c']) for v in xx]
    shp = [*zip_longest(*[lns,rzs])]
    shp = [list(s) for s in shp]
    shp = [[*itertools.chain.from_iterable(s)] for s in shp]

    xd  = dict([[ "input_{}".format(i+1),np.array(y)] for i,y in [*enumerate(xx)]])
    yd  = dict([["output_{}".format(i+1),np.array(y)] for i,y in [*enumerate(yy)]])

    ds  = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xd, yd))
    ds  = ds.shuffle(10000)

    # CHANGED: the following line, to run images import (also moved epeat instruction later)
    ds  = ds.map(
        lambda x, y: (
            {key: read_image(path, shp[i]) for i, (key, path) in enumerate(x.items())},
            y
        ),
        num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE
    )
    ds  = ds.repeat()
    ds  = ds.batch(batch_size) if batch_size else ds 
    ds  = ds.prefetch(AUTOTUNE) 
    return ds
```

---

#### Initial answer (before question edit):

I will only deal with the exception raised by `load_image` in this answer, but there might be additional work to perform on the rest - I did not test for that, not having a convenient dataset at hand.

The exception message is actually quite explicit: you are passing a scalar element (*e.g.* `n` in `[(k, tf.map_fn(lambda x: read_image(x, shp), n, dtype=tf.float32)) for k,n in pout]`) as `elems` argument to `tf.map_fn`, when it expects a tensor (or (possibly nested) list or tuple of tensors), as clearly specified in its documentation.

You are also using `tf.map_fn` the wrong way in the quoted line of code, because basically you are mixing it up with a python intention list, when you should use either one or the other.

With intention list (also replacing the useless previous lines of the `load_image` function):
`pl = {path: (load_image(path, shp), res) for path, res in x.items()}`

With `tf.map_fn`:

```py
# Read all images, return two tensors, one with images, the other with resolutions.
# (so, resolutions inclusion in this is actually useless and should be redesigned)
pl = tf.map_fn(
    lambda args: (read_image(args[0], shp), args[1]),
    [tf.convert_to_tensor(list(x)), tf.convert_to_tensor(list(x.values()))],
    dtype=(tf.float32, tf.float32)
)
# If you really, really want to return a dict, but is it an optimal design?
pl = {path: (pl[0][i], pl[1][i]) for i, path in enumerate(x)}
```

I do not know whether returning a dict specified in this way is optimal (or even compatible) with Dataset instantiation, however if the rest of your code is working, this should do the trick.

At any rate, if you want to iterate over a dict, go ahead and use either the first version or a modified version of the second one (which may have the advantage of parallelizing images reading).

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response!  I updated the post with the output as well a printout of the input data and some intermediate printouts.  Does anything pop out?

Comment: Hi, thanks for clarifying things as to what the inputs look like and what you are trying to achieve. For clarity, since you mentioned modifying it, could you share the code for the function you ran that triggered the exception?

Comment: I just added the latest function and edited out some of the cruft.

dataset_prep is the triggering function.  Unfortunately I don't have a simple test harness setup to run with out bringing in the whole system.

Comment: @eigen_enthused The edited answer should fix your issue; let me know if there are additional bugs.

Comment: I just attempted the latest, but I'm back to "elems must be a 1+ dimensional Tensor, not a scalar" error.  How would you frame it without dictionaries?

Comment: That does not make sense... Following my answer, you should not be using `tf.map_fn` anymore. As for not using dict, I should post some code in a moment.